# Jest - Mock callback in function fs.writefile

Tags: node.js, callback, jestjs, mocking

I am stucking for 3 hours on this topic. I dont find a solution how to test the if(err) branch in this code:

```
    function createFile(data){

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    try {

        if(data === null || data === undefined){
            throw new Error(errorMessages.noDataDefined);
        }

        let internalJobId = uuid.v4();
        let fileName = 'project_name' + internalJobId + '.xml';

        fs.writeFile(config.tmpPath + fileName, data, function (err) {
            if (err){
                throw new Error(err.toString());
            } else {
                resolve(fileName);
            }
            
        });

    } catch (error) {
        return reject(error);
    }
});
```

}

This test passes but it does not call the if (err) { throw new Error(err.toString())}

I have to find a solution, how the callback returns an error, but I dont get the right solution.

```
test('Error', () => {

    jest.mock('fs', () => ({
        writeFile: jest.fn((path, data, callback) => callback(Error('some error')))
      }));

    return expect(createFile('Does not matter')).rejects.toThrow('some error');


});
```

But with this test there is even not a reject, so there is never thrown an error. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out there.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. You omitted relevant pieces of code. There's no createFile. If it wraps fs.writeFile with `new Promise` then there is a mistake because throwing an error inside fs.writeFile callback won't result in rejected promise.

Comment: Hello, I have updatetet the question. I am checking for an error, throw this error and in the catch block I reject the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems here. One is that `fs.writeFile` isn't correctly mocked. Another is that `createFile` doesn't correctly handle errors and can't meet the expectation.

`jest.mock` affects modules that haven't been imported yet and hoisted to the top of the block (or above imports when used at top level). It cannot affect `fs` if a module that uses it has already been imported. Since `fs` functions are commonly used with their namespace, they can also be mocked as methods.

It should be either:

```
// at top level
import fs from 'fs';
jest.mock('fs', ...);
...
```

Or:

```
// inside test
jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').mockImplementation(...);
...
```

And be asserted to make the test more specific:

```
expect(fs.writeFile).toBeCalledTimes(1);
expect(fs.writeFile).toBeCalledWith(...);
return expect(createFile('Does not matter'))...
```

Promise constructor doesn't need `try..catch` because it already catches all  *synchronous* error inside it and cannot catch asynchronous errors from callbacks. For places where a promise needs to be rejected, `reject` can be preferred for consistency.

That an error is thrown inside `fs.writeFile` callback is a mistake and results in pending promise. It has no chance to reject the promise, has no chance to be caught with `try..catch` outside the callback and causes uncaught error.

It should be:

```
function createFile(data){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if(data === null || data === undefined){
            reject(new Error(errorMessages.noDataDefined));
        }

        let internalJobId = uuid.v4();
        let fileName = 'project_name' + internalJobId + '.xml';

        fs.writeFile(config.tmpPath + fileName, data, function (err) {
            if (err){
                reject(new Error(err.toString()); // reject(err) ?
            } else {
                resolve(fileName);
            }            
        });
    });
}
```

In order to keep nesting to minimum, parts that don't need promisification can be moved outside the constructor with the function being `async`:

```
async function createFile(data){
    if(data === null || data === undefined){
        throw new Error(errorMessages.noDataDefined);
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {    
        let internalJobId = uuid.v4();
        ...
```

There is also [`fs.promises` API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) that may not need to be promisified.

Also notice that `new Error(err.toString())` may be unnecessary and result in unexpected error message and so fail the assertion. The promise can be rejected with `err` as is. If the purpose is to remove unnecessary error information or change error stack, it should be `new Error(err.message)`.

Comment: Thank you for helpful response. I changed the code in that way that the try / catch block is removed. Also the first if statement is above the promise and in an async func now. But all the changes make the code cleaner but it seems still to change nothing regarding my first question. I am still not able to mock a function that this line "reject(new Error(err.toString()); // reject(err) ?" is covered. I dont know, if it is only for me but I am new at Jest and find the mocking part more complex than the most parts of developing.

Comment: This was one part of the problem that you likely didn't experience yet. I updated. It's not that hard but may need to have some idea how it messes with Node modules and what's going on under the hood to use it comfortably.

Comment: unfortunately this one "jest.spyOn('fs', 'writeFile').mockImplementation(...);" results in "Cannot spy on a primitive value; string given"

Comment: That was a typo, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

```
 jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').mockImplementation((f, d, callback) => {
                callback('some error');
 });
```

Thanks to Estus Flask!

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that this is incompliant mock that's unable to spot described problem with error handling because it triggers an error synchronously, while writeFile is asynchronous. Should be `=> setTimeout(() => { callback('some error') })`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have changed the code. The coverage was 100 % in both cases, but this is more compliant, I understand. So im am eger to try it out with s3 Api now, i think regarding to that, this was an easy thing. Have to learn a lot in jest, but someday I will understand everything right, I hope ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following three lines of code did the job for me:

```
import * as fs from 'fs/promises';

jest.mock('fs/promises');

jest.spyOn(fs, 'writeFile').mockImplementation( your implementation here );
```